# Using useEffect and useRef to render Light-Weight Chart, but gets error

Tags: reactjs

Lightweight-chart creates its own canvas and I'm unable to center the graph in the page or move it anywhere. I tried without using any hooks. It renders the graph, but it won't respond to any css I assign it o so I started using useRef, but still not working. I get "TypeError: t.appendChild is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Chart.css';

const Chart = ({stock}) => {

    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);
    const chartRef = useRef();


    useEffect(() => {

            const chart = createChart(chartRef, { width: 500, height: 400 });
            const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
            lineSeries.setData(stockChartDatas);
            chart.timeScale().fitContent();
    },[])


    return (
            <div className="chart-container">
            <h2>Interactive 5 Years Historical Daily Chart</h2>
            <div ref={chartRef} />
            </div>
        )
    }
export default Chart;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `chartRef.current`

```
const chart = createChart(chartRef.current, { width: 500, height: 400 });
```

Check this out 
https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-wright-wkn5q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks! Now I can move the chart. ".current", I will remember that.